# How can control bind param variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm selecting a list of exam IDs from my database, and then using a random one to select from a list of questions. If there are no matching questions, I want to pick another random ID and try again. Here is the code I have now; it works but will not return any questions for some of the exams.

```
$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM exam WHERE level=? AND flag=?");
$query->bind_param("si",$level,$flag);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$resultCount= $result->num_rows;
if($resultCount>0)
{
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {   
        $list[]=$row['id'];
   }
    $indexRand=array_rand($list, 1);
    $query->close();
}
$query2 = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE exam_id=?");
$query2->bind_param('i', $list[$indexRand]);
$query2->execute();
$question_result = $query2->get_result();
$resultCount2= $question_result->num_rows;
if($resultCount2>0)
{  
    while($questions_rows=$question_result->fetch_assoc())
    {   
        $list2[]=$questions_rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry my English no so good :)

Comment: and thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this in a single database query.

```
SELECT q.*
  FROM questions q
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT e.id
    FROM exams e
    LEFT JOIN questions q ON (e.id = q.exam_id)
    WHERE level = ? AND flag = ? AND q.id IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
  ) i ON (q.exam_id = i.id)
  WHERE i.id = q.exam_id
```

You join in a subquery as a table in your query. The subquery selects a single random item from the exams table, and itself joins in the questions table, to make sure that some questions exist. Demo is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b394af/1

Comment: sorry, When I run this code every time, show me just one type of exam_id rows  from the questions table

Comment: bro can you help me more please i want every time runing my code show me ids that be in questions table like exan_id but when i every time i runing your code just show me one result instead of random results

Comment: Works fine for me at the demo. Suggest you look at your data to ensure you have appropriate values for the outcome you desire.

Comment: bro plz see this images my codes and DB i dont understand what you say about? every thing ok but not work :( https://pasteboard.co/IchBs8K.png  https://pasteboard.co/IchB39s.png https://pasteboard.co/IchBs8K.png

Comment: bro thanks i wrok on it until fix it :D ty bro sorry if i harrasing you :) thanks thanks thnaks